# ldconfig error:"is not a symbolic link" when using Linux loader

Tags: linux, linker, makefile, gnu-make

When running:

```
    sudo /sbin/ldconfig
```

the following error appears:

```
    /sbin/ldconfig: /usr/local/lib/ is not a symbolic link
```

When I run the `file` command, the below appears:

```
    file /usr/local/lib/
    /usr/local/lib/: directory
```

Inside `/usr/local/lib/` there are three libraries that I use. I'll call them here as `lib1`, `lib2` and `lib3`.

Now, when I do an `ldd` on my binary it results:

```
    lib1.so => not found
    lib2.so => not found
    lib3.so => /usr/local/lib/lib3.so (0x00216000)
```

But all of them are in the same folder as `/usr/local/lib/{lib1,lib2,lib3}.so`.

Every time I run `ldconfig`, the same error appears:

```
/usr/local/lib/ is not a symbolic link
```

I thought `/usr/local/lib` should be declared twice in `/etc/ld.conf.d/*.conf`, but not:

```
    sudo egrep '\/usr\/local' /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
    projectA.conf.old:/usr/local/projectA/lib
    local.conf:/usr/local/lib
```

`ld.so.conf` only includes `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`, so this `*.old` isn't processed, and it refers to `/usr/local/projectA/lib`.

After a time trying I deleted all lib1 and lib2 (at some point I tested it on binary's folder), the same error occurs.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I ran into this issue with the Oracle 11R2 client. Not sure if the Oracle installer did this or someone did it here before I arrived.  It was not 64-bit vs 32-bit, all was 64-bit.

The error was that `libexpat.so.1` was not a symbolic link.

It turned out that there were two identical files, `libexpat.so.1.5.2` and `libexpat.so.1`.  Removing the offending file and making it a symlink to the 1.5.2 version caused the error to go away.

Makes sense that you'd want the well-known name to be a symlink to the current version.  If you do this, it's less likely that you'll end up with a stale library.

Comment: did they share the same md5sum result before they're gone?

Comment: It wasn't someone before you. The client installer does this. The fix suggested works.

Comment: Yes. As he mentioned i also see identical files. Some one rename *.so to *.so.old and copied *.so from the latest driver same name(libmyodbc5w.so.old, libmyodbc5w.so). This could also lead into this issue. rm libmyodbc5w.so.old resolved the issue.

Comment: Had the same issue with `libcudnn.so.5`. It's identical to others, but caused ldconfig error. just symlinking fixed it. Any idea why does it happen?

Comment: dumb installer scripts, I guess.

Comment: I am having this error with 'libcudnn.so.4'
In the same directory there are two other files 'libcudnn.so' and 'libcudnn.so.4.0.7'. They all are identical, but I am not sure which one to remove or which one to symlink.

Comment: I would leave the most specifically named file (4.0.7) as a real file, and make the other two symlinks to that.  Do ensure they are all identical before you delete.

Comment: This fix applies to lots of different files (it happens a lot with CUDA related files). Essentially, delete the non-symbolic one and recreate it so it links to the latest version. So in this case `cd` to the directory where the file is found, call `ls -a | grep libexpat`, this will show the `libexpat.so.1.5.2` and `libexpat.so.1`. Call `rm libexpat.so.1; ln -s libexpat.so.1.5.2 libexpat.so.1`. You may need to use `sudo`for this.

Answer (score 9):

I simply ran the command below:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/
```

Now it is working fine.

Comment: can you add a line or two of explanation regarding this?

Comment: Worked for me while installing Oracle 19c on RHEL7. The error was    "/sbin/ldconfig: /lib64/libsnmp++.so.33 is not a symbolic link"

Comment: Why would that be the solution to the symlink problem?? Because if forces the search of a lib into another path, and it won't meet the problem? But the missing symlink (due to a copy for instance) remains...

Comment: Perhaps because it excludes the path that contains the duplicate files.

Answer (score 8):

Solved, at least at the point of the question.

I searched in the web before asking, and there were no conclusive solution, the reason why this error is: lib1.so and lib2.so are not OK, very probably where not compiled for a 64 bit PC, but for a 32 bits machine otherwise lib3.so is a 64 bits lib. At least that is my hypothesis.

VERY unfortunately `ldconfig` doesn't give a clean error message informing that it could not load the library, it only pumps:

**ldconfig: /folder_where_the_wicked_lib_is/ is not a symbolic link**

I solved this when I removed the libs not found by `ldd` over the binary. Now it's easier that I know where lies the problem.

My ld version:
GNU ld version 2.20.51, and I don't know if a most recent version has a better message for its users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the path of the libraries inside /etc/ld.so.conf, and rerun ldconfig to upate the list

Other possibility is to include in the env variable  LD_LIBRARY_PATH the path to your library, and rerun the executable.

check the symbolic links if they point to a valid library ...

You can add the path directly in /etc/ld.so.conf, without include...

run `ldconfig -p` to see whether your library is well included in the cache.

Comment: The path already is at: local.conf, its content:
/usr/local/lib
on ld.so.conf is including every file.conf inside its specif folder:
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf

Comment: are you sure it is processed well ?

Comment: That is one of the possibilies, but it found lib3.so that is exactly on that folder.
/usb/local/lib holds {lib1.so, lib2.so, lib3.so}

Comment: run ldconfig -p | grep lib[[:digit:]][.]so, and check if all work. This is all that I can help you with.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't appear, the main thing is the non sense error /sbin/ldconfig: /usr/local/lib/ is not a symbolic link
for a folder, course it's not a link? ld is waiting a link? why is it waiting?

Comment: If you provide more informations, I can help you. But from what you say, I cannot say more. If it does not appear, that means that you did not configure the linker properly, and have to do what I said in my firstmessage.

Comment: My friend, (as I said in my question), the MAIN thing IS the error message, and this error message happens when I run ldconfig. What more info do you need?

Comment: you can use 'ldconfig' command with this answer like:

 sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda -p

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced the same issue,
The solution for it is :
the file for which you are getting the error is probably a duplicated file of the actual file with another version. So just the removal of a particular file on which errors are thrown can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

simple run in shell : sudo apt-get install --reinstall libexpat1
got same problem with libxcb - solved in this way - very fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically versions are used. For example you could have `lib1.so.1` which is your actual library with minor version (could be also a patch version like `*.so.1.1`). And then there should be a "major" symlink to your minor (or patch) version. Like `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/lib1.so.1 /usr/local/lib1.so`.

If you have  patch version of some library `libsomething.so.1.3` then your major and minor symlinks booth should point to the patch version. While you can make symlink chain like `major` -> `minor` -> `patch` (or `generic`, `major`, `specific`. Depending who the reader of this answer is.) quite often it is not preferred by "experts". This is just "opinions". Keep that in mind.

`/usr/local/lib` typically is used for **custom** 32-bit libraries and `/usr/local/lib64` for **custom** 64-bit libraries.

**custom** are those libraries which you develop by yourself or which you explicitly (manually) install on your system.

To know what architecture library it is you use `file /usr/local/lib/lib1.so.1`. It will tell you is it 32-bit or 64-bit. So, you move your library in the appropriate directory (this is not mandatory, but just a good convention).

`/usr/local/{lib,lib64}` directories typically is not cached (included) by `ldconfig` by default. You must "teach" `ldconfig` to cache libraries in those paths as well.

To do so, you edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and add the line like `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` (relative path). This effectively tells `ldconfig` to load other config files from `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory.

Then you can create as many `ldconfig` config files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` as you want, but good start could be `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/extra.conf`.

Within this file you tell which other paths `ldconfig` should cache (include). In our case just add 2 lines - `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib64`.

After all this, you just need to update your shared library cache with `sudo ldconfig`.

Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is mostly "development-only tool" when you want to load some specific library/ies. Typically you should not use/set it.

To see, if your library is cached you use `ldconfig -p | grep libsomelib`.