# How to solve this kind of symbolic link issue while following leveldb installation instruction?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I want to know how to solve this many errors. This error came while I am following installation instructions for laveldb.

```
sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev
wget https://leveldb.googlecode.com/files/leveldb-1.9.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf leveldb-1.9.0.tar.gz
cd leveldb-1.9.0
make
sudo mv libleveldb.* /usr/local/lib
cd include
sudo cp -R leveldb /usr/local/include
sudo ldconfig
```

Same error appear while installing libsnappy-dev but at that time I ignored this but after this command again I encountered with these errors.

```
kamlesh@kamlesh-VirtualBox:~/db/leveldb/include$ sudo ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libz.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.9 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libzmq.so.3 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libczmq.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libyajl.so.2 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libtld.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libjansson.so.4 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libarchive.so.13 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libmodpbase64.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/liburiparser.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libnsmagic.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libIP2Location.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libwbxml2.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libGeoIP.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

Please Suggest me some solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Those are actually warnings and not errors. Dynamic linked libraries are supposed to be symlinked to the full version. e.g. `libfoo.so --> libfoo.so.1 --> libfoo.so.1.2`. You can fix this yourself manually.

Comment: Thanks for the comment now it is working fine. I have fixed manually

Comment: This solution worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542255/ldconfig-error-is-not-a-symbolic-link